# Some confusion about the working mechanism of ~/.bash_history

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

I'm confusing about the content in ~/.bash_history when I worked on several terminals. How does it work on saving the history in different terminals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the history file is only read when starting up, and only written to when exiting. As a result, if you startup multiple shells at the same time, only the history from the last one to exit is going to be preserved. The history generated from the rest will be overwritten.

There are a couple of ways you can adjust this behaviour. One is by adding `shopt -s histappend` to your .bashrc. This option will cause the history file to be appended to rather than overwritten on shell exit.

You can further adjust this behaviour by having bash perform an append after every command, by adding the following to your `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable in your `.bashrc`: `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;"`. This causes the command `history -a` to run every time a prompt is printed.

When using both of the above adjustments, the bash history file will be continually appended to by each of your shells no matter how many are open. The one caveat is that each of those shells won't see the commands ran by the other shells, since the history file is only read on startup. You can try to manually read those entries into the shells current history by calling `history -n`, but I've seen some oddities when doing so with multiple shells constantly appending. Tread carefully if you try automating that and you care deeply about your history.

Comment: Is it at the risk of the size of .bash_history growing huge? Or there is some limit on the number of lines recorded?

Comment: The history will automatically remove the oldest entries once the filesize has passed the `HISTFILESIZE` environment variable. I prefer keeping a lot of history, so I have had `.bash_history` file sizes in the tens of MB without any performance issues. As long as you aren't on a lower-RAM, low-CPU machine, large history files shouldn't cause any noticeable slowdown. I'd suspect you wouldn't notice much until you started reaching hundreds of MB, and that's a lot of history.